# Custom ArrayAdapter for Spinner getView() not called

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I'm having a problem with custom array adapter. I read all threads on stack about it and still can't solve this issue. I used the code from this question (and it was not working so I made some small changes: [Spinner with custom ArrayAdapter for objects not displaying selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678521/spinner-with-custom-arrayadapter-for-objects-not-displaying-selected-item)

The problem is that I create my adapter and:
 1. getCount shows proper value (244)
 2. getView is not being called
 3. getDropdown view not called too.

Can you please help me out with this one?

Adapter class:

```
public class DishesFilterCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dish> {

private List<Dish> items;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;

public DishesFilterCustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<Dish> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.items = objects;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (v == null) {
        v = new TextView(context);
    }
    v.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_light));
    v.setText(items.get(position).dishName);

    return v;
}

@Override
public Dish getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_mode_payer_item, null);
    }
    TextView lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewForAdapter);
    lbl.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_light));
    lbl.setText(items.get(position).dishName);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public List<Dish> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

code from a fragment:

```
        mDishList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDishList.addAll(getAllDishesSegregatedList(getAllDishesList()));
        mDishesAdapter = new DishesFilterCustomArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.payment_mode_payer_item, R.id.textViewForAdapter, mDishList);
        //mDishesAdapter.add(new Dish(getString(R.string.filter_receipt_history_by_dish_name)));
        dishesFilterSpinner.setAdapter(mDishesAdapter);
```

mDishList size is 244 and it matches getCount() value.

Comment: Are you certain that the `dishesFilterSpinner` you're setting the `Adapter` on is the one you see on-screen? For example, if that `Fragment` code is in `onCreateView()`, are you sure you're returning the `View` you're calling `findViewById()` on to get `dishesFilterSpinner`?

Comment: How did you check that those methods are not being called? Add Log.d(...) to each method, run your app, click on the spinner and look at your logcat.

Comment: I did checked those method with Log.d, I just haven't posted it here as it's useless. Mike M. thanks for the tip. Yes, it appeared that I had a view  with the same id set to visibilty gone. Apart form that I had further mistakes in my code and I'm going to edit my question with changes. Again, Mike M. great thanks for your contribution! Have a good day!

Comment: @Jan: would you roll back your "solved" change, and add that as an answer proper? There is a button to allow you to answer your own question. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing  :) Forgot about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. First mistake was that I had two views with same id and I set my adapter to the one which not visible.

Second was that I had some mistakes in code of my custom adapter. I post it below.

```
public class DishesFilterCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dish> {

private List<Dish> items;
private Context context;

public DishesFilterCustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<Dish> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.items = objects;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt_history_spinner_item, null);
    }
    TextView lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.receiptHistorySpinnerItemTextView);
    lbl.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_light));
    lbl.setText(items.get(position).dishName);

    return v;
}

@Override
public Dish getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt_history_spinner_item, null);
    }
    TextView lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.receiptHistorySpinnerItemTextView);
    lbl.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_light));
    lbl.setText(items.get(position).dishName);

    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public List<Dish> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

Mike.M thanks you for your help!

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the "getDropDownView", so when selected everything looked good, but when selecting, my custom view was not filled.